# Custom MatDatePicker

Tags: angular

Creating a custom material date picker for form controls. The requirement is that text input and date selection will both work using moment.js to validate the date. Currently all is working except when typing in input dates, dates appear automatically. Looking to use two methods one for text input and the other for mat-datepicker element. Anyone with custom form control experience please advise.

**update: Need to trigger event for the method addEvent only after typed date input has been fully entered

**datepicker.html**

```
      <div class="form-inline">
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker"
               [value]="dateValue"
               [min]="minDate"
               [max]="maxDate"
               [style.width]="inputWidth"
               class="form-control"
               [textMask]="{mask: maskDateNum}"
               autocomplete="off"
               (dateInput)="addEvent('input', $event)"
               [placeholder]="placeholder">


        <mat-icon
          id="clear-btn"
          *ngIf="!disabled && (dateValue != null)"
          (click)="clearDate()" >clear</mat-icon>
      <mat-icon
        *ngIf="disabled || (dateValue == null)"></mat-icon>
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [hidden]="disabled" [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      <p *ngIf="!isInputValid()">Input is invalid</p>
    </div>
```

**datepicker.ts**

```
export class DatePicker implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator, OnInit {
  @Input() disabled = false;
  @Input() required = false;
  @Input() minDate = null;
  events: string[] = [];
  @Input() maxDate = null;
  @Input() public inputWidth = '120px';
  maskDateNum: any[] = [/\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/];


  /**
   * Set the value of the date set by user, notice the underscore infront of the datevalue
   */

  @Input() _dateValue: string = null;

  /**
   * Placeholder value for the material control input
   */
  @Input() public placeholder: string = null;

  /**
   * The date format to use with default format but allowing you to pass a custom date format
   */
  @Input() private format = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
  private inFormat = 'M/D/YYYY';
  private orFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
  /**
   * setting matFormField to true wraps the input in a matformfield
   */
  @Input() matFormField = false;

  @Output()
  change = new EventEmitter();

  get dateValue() {
    const v = moment(this._dateValue, this.inFormat);
    if (this._dateValue === 'Invalid date' || !v.isValid()) {
      return null;
    }
    if (v.isValid() && v.format(this.format) !== 'Invalid date') {
      return v;
    }
    return null;
  }

  set dateValue(val) {
    if (moment(val).format(this.inFormat) === 'Invalid date') {
      this._dateValue = null;
    } else {
      this._dateValue = moment(val).format(this.inFormat);
    }

    this.propagateChange(this._dateValue);
  }

  addEvent(type: string, event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
    if (event.value === null) {
      this.dateValue = null;
    }
    if (event.value.toString().length > 8) {
      this.dateValue = moment(event.value, this.orFormat);
    }
  }


  writeValue(value: any) {
    if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
      this.dateValue = moment(value, this.inFormat);
    }
    if (value === null) {
      this.dateValue = null;
    }
  }

  propagateChange = (_: any) => {
    this.change.emit();
  }

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched() {
  }

  clearDate() {
    this.dateValue = null;
  }

  registerOnValidatorChange(fn: () => void): void {
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
  }

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    const val = control.value;
    console.log(val);
    if ((val == null || val == undefined || val == 'Invalid date' || val == '') && this.required) {
      return {
        required: true
      };
    }
    return null;
  }


  isInputValid(): boolean {
    return this.validate(new FormControl(
      this.dateValue
    )) === null;

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
}
```